# Show $A=(I-S)(I+S)^{-1}$ is an orthogonal matrix if $S$ is a real antisymmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to show that if $S$ is a real antisymmetric matrix ($S^T=-S$), then $A=(I-S)(I+S)^{-1}$ is an orthogonal matrix. $I$ is the identity matrix.

To show that $A$ is orthogonal, i.e. $A^T=A^{-1}$, I first calculated   $A^T$ and $A^{-1}$:

$$A^T=[(I+S)^{-1}]^T(I-S)^T=[(I+S)^T]^{-1}(I-S)^T=(I+S^T)^{-1}(I-S^T)=(I-S)^{-1}(I+S)$$
$$A^{-1}=(I+S)(I-S)^{-1}$$

How can I then show that $(I-S)^{-1}(I+S)=(I+S)(I-S)^{-1}$ so that I can prove $A$ is orthogonal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(I-S)^{-1}(I+S)=(I+S)(I-S)^{-1}$$

$$ \iff$$

$$(I+S)=(I-S)(I+S)(I-S)^{-1}$$

$$ \iff$$

$$(I+S)(I-S)=(I-S)(I+S)$$

$$ \iff$$

$$I-S+S-S^2=I+S-S+S^2.$$

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to note that by the Cayley Hamilton theorem, $(I-S)^{-1}$ can be expressed as a polynomial of $S$, and for any two polynomials $p,q$ we have $p(S)q(S) = q(S)p(S)$.

For a direct proof, we could note that
\begin{align}
(I + S)(I - S)^{-1}&= (2I - (I - S))(I - S)^{-1}\\
&= 2(I - S)^{-1} - I\\
&= (I - S)^{-1}[2I - (I - S)]\\
&=(I - S)^{-1}(I + S).
\end{align}